# Given $g(x)$ is continuous and $\int_0^a g(x)dx = 0$, $\forall a\geq0$, prove that $g(x)=0$, $\forall x \geq0$. Proof without using FTC?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification

> Given $g(x)$ is continuous and $\int_0^a g(x)dx = 0 \ \forall a\geq0$, prove that $g(x)=0 \ \forall x \geq0$.

From STEP exam - the examiners report said that almost all attempts that didn't use the FTC failed. So I'm wondering what a valid attempt that doesn't use FTC would look like.

I thought about, roughly speaking, trying to prove that if there's a given interval with $g(x)>0$ over some positive $x$ then there must be an interval with $g(x)<0$ over some smaller $x$ which implies a smaller nonzero interval of the opposite sign and so on until we reach a nonzero interval with 0 as its lower limit which would be a contradiction, but functions like $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ make this awkward.

So here is my second attempt.

Suppose $g(\alpha)>0$. We also have $\int_0^\alpha g(x)dx = 0$. But because $g(x)$ is continuous, there must exist $\beta>\alpha$ such that $g(x)>0 \ \forall x \in (\alpha,\beta)$. Therefore $\int_0^\beta g(x)dx > \int_0^\alpha g(x)dx = 0$ which is a contradiction. The case where $g(\alpha)<0$ is similar.

Does this work?

Comment: Yes your second attempt is correct, using the  fact that $\int_0^b f(x)dx=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Comment: You should mention which properties of integrals your are allowed to use. Your second attempt uses $g(x)>f(x)\Rightarrow\int g(x)dx>\int f(x)dx$ (with $f=0$). But often we only want to assume $g(x)\geq f(x)\Rightarrow\int g(x)dx\geq\int f(x)dx.$ In this case, it is easier to try to get a stronger result from the continuity, i.e. there must exist $\beta>\alpha$ and $h>0$ such that $g(x)\geq h\forall x\in(\alpha,\beta)$ and then use $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}g(x)dx\geq \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}hdx = (\beta-\alpha)h > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

My idea: let $\int_{0}^{a}g(x) \,dx=0$ and (where $\epsilon>0$, and $\epsilon$ is small) also $\int_{0}^{a+\epsilon}g(x) \,dx=0$. So, letting $\epsilon$ be tiny, we see $\int_{a}^{a+\epsilon}g(x) \,dx=\int_{0}^{a+\epsilon}g(x) \,dx-  \int_{0}^{a}g(x) \,dx=0$.

Note we can approximate $g(x)$ on $(a,a+\epsilon)$ as $g(a+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)$, so $\int_{a}^{a+\epsilon}g(x) \,dx=0$ means $\epsilon \times g(a+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)=0$. This tells us $0=g(a+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)$. In the formal sense, I am using ideas similar to your method in the second proof.